# Scraping data using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying scrape the data into a dictionary from this site,

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import requests 
from pprint import pprint

page = requests.get('https://webscraper.io/') 
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "lxml")

info = []
for x in range(1,7):
    items = soup.findAll("div",{"class":f"info{x}"})
    info.append(items)
```

however, the HTML tags are not being removed.

Comment: Try items.text instead of items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `.text`. Then to get in the way you want, would need to do a bit of string manipulation.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import requests 
from pprint import pprint

url = 'https://webscraper.io/'
page = requests.get(url) 
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "lxml")


info = []
for x in range(1,7):
    item = soup.find("div",{"class":"info%s" %x}).text.strip().replace('\n',': ')
    info.append(item)

info = '\n'.join(info)
print (info)
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might work? (Replace the webscraper.io url with your actual request URL; Also, you'd still need to clean up the \n characters from the output):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import requests 
from pprint import pprint

page = requests.get('https://webscraper.io/') 
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "lxml")

info = []
for x in range(1,7):
    items = soup.findAll("div",{"class":f"info{x}"})
    info += [item.text for item in items]
```

I.e. item.text, and concatenate the resulting array with info